# Differece between export and no export in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

```
// test1.js
   var a = 5;


// test2.js
export default () => {
  var a = 5;
}


// main.js
import test1 from './test1';
import test2 from './test2';
```

I'm little confused because I can import files which haven't export and have export and it still works. So what is a difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of modules is that they have scope and expose only what you precisely told them to by using `export`

In your first example you won't be able to access `var a` from the outside of module (eg. from another module)

In the second example, you export a `function` which has `var a` defined inside, so the outcome will be identical. But if you do `export default var a = 5`, you would be able access variable `a` from other module using `import`